# Disappearing scrollbar in Windows like in OS X Lion

Tags: windows, osx-lion, scrollbar

Is there any tweak or utility for Windows that can make the scrollbar behave like in OS X Lion? In OS X Lion, the scrollbar appears only when the interface is interacted with and disappears after a while.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible.

Each Application implements it's own scrollbar. Even trying to make them all transparent isn't a given since each application can override the system colors.

Answer (score 1):

`**UPDATE - JANUARY 2016 **`

For the Windows users on Google Chrome who still yearn for iOS-like scrollbars, there are IMHO 2 solid options:

- (1) [`jQuery NiceScroll`](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) w/ the [`TamperMonkey`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) extension or
- (2) opening `chrome://flags/` in Google Chrome and enable `Overlay Scrollbars` (`chrome://flags/#overlay-scrollbars`). With `Overlay Scrollbars` being native to Google Chrome you can expect better performance vs jQuery NiceScroll. The choice is yours...

---

If you use Firefox and have the Greasemonkey or Scriptish add-on installed, you are in luck! Head over to [UserScripts.org](http://userscripts.org) and search for [grease.nicescroll](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/119910). It's a jQuery plugin that was converted into a userscript so that everyone could iOS-like scrollbars in Firefox!